# Libev error when compilng

Tags: c, syntax-error, static-libraries, libev

I'm trying to compile a code with gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -DNDEBUG -pedantic -ansi flags and to use libev library. I am getting the following errors in eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’  Project     line 827, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’  Project     line 820, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’  Project     line 821, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
make: *** [src/Object/MySockets/MySockets.o] Error 1    Project         C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’    Project     line 551, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int’   Project     line 559, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘unsigned’  Project     line 825, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘unsigned’  Project     line 826, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’  Project     line 822, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’  Project     line 823, external location: /usr/include/ev.h  C/C++ Problem
```

I've installed the libev-dev package in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-ansi` flag causes the compiler to only accept C89 code, and will only enable C89 features in the standard header files (of glibc/gcc).

libev isn't designed to be compiled by a strict c89 compiler, it needs at least a posix (or possibly win32) system - and likely it uses a few c99 features as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I asked yesterday on the IRC channel of libev if it is ansi c compliant. They told me that it is. So I was not wrong. Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: If you could add solution to this problem then it would actually help. :-)

Comment: @jparthj The problem is the `-ansi` flag, and the solution is to NOT use the -ansi or similar flags.

Comment: ok i got that, but in my case i have not used -ansi flag and the problem exists.

Comment: @jparthj Then, assuming it is the exact same error, you've used -std=c99 or something similar. Or you're on a rather weird platform, or your program has some #defines that mess with libev or the standard libc headers.